# Convert large text file from a specific character set to UTF8

Tags: c#, text, encoding, character-encoding, io

I need to convert very large text files (usually over 100 MB) of character encoding "windows-1252" to UTF8 using the smallest amount of memory.

Anyone know what the fastest / lowest memory overhead way to do this is?

I'm assuming some uber-fast StreamReader/StreamWriter combination!

thanks

Comment: How can this not be constructive? This is an actual problem.  You can't load a huge text file in memory in a resource constrained environment and then just use File.WriteAllText().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to allocate all data you operate on chunks of it by

- first reading it with StreamReader with  `"windows-1252"`
- in the same iteration writing it with [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/f5f5x7kt.aspx), with specified `UTF-8`

Answer (score 2):

The [`Encoding.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyt2e46a.aspx) method operates on `byte[]` - you can call this with a small buffer, reading from your original file then writing to a new file. If the original file uses a variable byte encoding you need to be very careful to only read into the buffer on character boundaries (if possible).

This will use as much or as little memory as you wish - depending on the buffer size you select.